# Date format in javascript and SQL

Tags: javascript, jquery, sql, date

I have a string "03/31/2017". I need to pass it as a Date to the SQL database. I tried to use `new Date("03/31/2017")` but it returns **Thu Mar 30 2017 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)** Is there anyway I can keep the original date format as a data object without using momentum or anyother library. I can't use any library but jQuery.

Comment: Mysql or SQL-Server? please remove the incompatible tag

Comment: @Jens just fixed the tag!

Comment: You mean Y-m-d format

Comment: you get it as an input from a form? I have used php with mysql and it suffices to make the input of type date in the form. And send it to the database as a string. I dont know about jQuery though

Comment: @RanaGhosh I meant keep it as mm/dd/YYYY format but as a date object too. That's how the dates are set in the database and they are as object types and when I run the query i get an error on the database because of date format since Thu Mar 30 2017 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time) it's getting passed instead of 03/31/2017

Comment: Are you using jQuery UI in your project?

Comment: Also, are you storing dates as string in your database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct date format for Javascript is: YYYY-MM-DD

```
    var dt = new Date('2017-03-27');
```

To be safer, do NOT use a string to specify the date, instead supply the parameters:

```
    var dt = new Date(2017, 3 - 1, 27); // months are zero based
```

Comment: your code keeps returning as an ISO format date. It needs to remain as mm/dd/yyyy and still being a date object. but it seem like it's not possible

Comment: @TamoDevelopers, take a look at https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_dates.asp, https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_date_new_string

Comment: I took a look to that before posting in here that way I new you code will keep giving me a ISO format :(. Thanks for the help tho!

Comment: @TamoDevelopers, the mysql date format is exactly the same format: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Comment: @SalmanA, then explain, just slate something and not give your reasons....as far as I can determine from the documentation, there is nothing wrong with what I have put.

Comment: @SPlatten sorry I just looked at your code and it uses slashes instead of dash. Anyway, using dates in `yyyy-mm-dd` format will also cause trouble because the browser might choose to convert the date to UTC.

Comment: @SalmanA, Read the documentation on what Date does...When you call new Date(), it will not be in UTC, the date/time returned with be in the local timezone, according to what the workstation is running, if you want a UTC version then call .toUTCString.

Comment: @SPlatten which documentation? [The documentation on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) discourages using the Date(string). it also states that the date-only strings _will_ be converted to UTC. What's worse is that different versions of JavaScript may or may not do the conversion.

Comment: @SalmanA, I'm referring to the documentation on https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp

Comment: @SPlatten avoid w3schools like plague. Their "documentation" is not official; most of the time it is incomplete, incorrect or outdated. For example, compare [this](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parse.asp) with [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse) and decide for yourself which one is better.